# Which deity would best fit a morally ambiguous rebel group fighting for freedom and equality in their home city?

Tags: forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

The characters in the campaign I’m currently running are very liberal and open-minded when it comes to non-human races. They even try to give non-humans that are typically viewed as evil (e.g. orcs) the benefit of the doubt. (At least at first. If the orcs attack, their lives are ended quickly). Naturally, the current story arc takes place in a city where non-humans are viewed as second second-class citizens and sometimes even bought and sold as slaves. I would like to present this mindset as normal in this particular city, in a way that the characters will have to begrudgingly accept it, because they cannot go up against everybody in the entire city.

But this city will also have its own morally ambiguous rebel group. Their goals are freedom and equality for everyone, but they think that the end justifies the means. So they are more like a left-wing terrorist group. There will be assassinations, kidnapped children, the whole nine yards. Now I need some kind of deity (or other figure) these rebels can rally behind. It’s easier to justify yourself when you do stuff in the name of a god.

But I’m not sure which deity would be appropriate. I looked at some domains, like Balance, Change, Chaos, Community, Freedom, Hope, Protection, Retribution, Strife and Vengeance, but none of those deities fit my needs perfectly. Currently, my top two contenders are Tymora and Ilmater, but I'm not fully satisfied with them.

So my question is: **Which deity would best fit a morally ambiguous rebel group fighting for freedom and equality in their home city?**

The continent where this campaign takes place is a hodgepodge of several areas from different campaign settings, but the world as a whole features the Faerûnian pantheon. So everything within the lore of the Forgotten Realms setting is fair game. I’m not married to the idea that it has to be a deity at all costs, so other comparable entities would be fine as well.

Comment: This question seems pretty much entirely opinion-based to me... It might be more appropriate on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: @V2Blast: At first, I thought so too. Then I found two similar questions which were fine: "Which Golarion deities would support and encourage a Witch-Hunter Inquisitor among their faithful?" and "Out of the Faerûnian and Greyhawkian pantheons, which magic deity would be a good fit for a specific witch-hunting cult?"

Comment: I disagree... while yes, there are probably a few deities that *could* fit the bill, I believe (although I'm not familiar enough with Forgotten Realms to be sure) that there will be a *best* one. I know that there is a deity *specifically* applicable in the Golarion (Pathfinder) universe.

Comment: What you describe are commonly referred to as anarchists, regarding the rebel group.  Is alignment of the deity of importance to this question, or not?

Comment: Well, in that case I'm glad I got some good answers before the question was closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hoar, the Doombringer, Poet of Justice.

Ilmater is a good choice and a more well known symbol, but your group is more focused on attacking the oppressors, rather than defending the oppressed. Using Ilmater as their symbol while kidnapping children is would be... seen as poor taste in faerun.

Loviatar is fine with causing pain, but when it comes to pain for a cause, the message falls apart. A group worshipping the Pain Mistress would never see acceptance and peace as the end goal, and the people would know it.

But let's take a look at the lesser deity of vengeance, **[Hoar](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Hoar). Hoar is Batman plus Kratos**. Originally from the Untheric pantheon, he hunted down and killed the Untheric God Ramman for crossing him. Tyr tried to recruit him to being a force for justice. Shar tried to recruit him as a force for destruction.

Hoar is all about punishing those who commit injustices. His followers are avengers who will get revenge for those who pray for it. He demands fitting punishment for criminals, and views those who extract just punishments as virtuous.

I think if you're trying to form an anti-hero team to fight injustice, Hoar is your guy.

Answer (score 1):

**The drow god Vhaeraun**

Vhaeraun is the Drow god of male Drow, who has the (to Drow) absurd belief that men and women are equally valuable. He's also the god of a whole bunch of deceptive stuff such as thievery. In addition, one of his domains is also trying to extend Drow control across the surface world.

Your terrorist group is a bunch of idealists who believe in equality, and idealists are fairly easy targets for tricksters. Vhaeraun could be manipulating them into believing that he's some sort of equality god and that he's "the Drow good guy". (he's really not, he's still thinks non-Drow are basically slaves or worse). He'd be perfectly okay with using underhanded tactics such as kidnapping and murder to get what you want, it's basically the kind of stuff that Drow live and breathe.

The actions of the rebel group would destabalize the city for an eventual Drow takeover, and all the "undesireables" that need to disappear in the name of equality can be "donated" to the Church of Vhaeraun, where they totally won't be shipped off to the Underdark to become slaves, honest. It gives you a god who has a good enough reason to try and push the whole 'equality' deal, while also giving you a good scapegoat in case you wish to end up having your players redeem the rebels. It even gives you ties for future campaigns.